# Command prompt batch renaming results in syntax error

Tags: windows, command-prompt, batch-rename

I need to rename 80k files in multiple folders & subfolders in the same directory. I have been trying to use `ren` but have been unsuccessful; I get an incorrect syntax error.

My old name looks like this:

`c:/users/alice/BiDIR_DOCS_2017_Nov08020423\Company,LLC##NA##7967425.00##7967425.00\Company LLC  A and A - Aug2017.pdf BiDIR_DOCS_2017_Nov08020423\Company, LLC##NA##7967425.00##7967425.00\document_@ (x.y.z)-test~.pdf`

and my new name looks like this:

`` c:/users/alice/BiDIR_DOCS_2017_Nov08020423\Company,LLC##NA##7967425.00##7967425.00\Company LLC  A and A - Aug2017.pdf BiDIR_DOCS_2017_Nov08020423\Company, LLC##NA##7967425.00##7967425.00\system, a old name~ ` to @ system b document (xyz)-test.pdf ``

I have the existing directory print in one column of Excel and in the next column what I want the directory print to be.

I'm not sure if I'm  starting my `ren` command at the right hierarchy of my directory, or if I need quotation marks to keep the spaces and symbols in my new name.

I have tried improvising and testing on my own without success and I cannot find an article online on point.

Comment: basically, i need to replace everything after the last "\" with new characters and keep everything before the last "\"

Comment: I have tried using ren oldname newname, but I can't seem to do multiple folders and subfolders and I can only succeed part of the time with one folder and one file

Answer (score 0):

Try FAR (find and replace) - it a free utility that works well.

http://findandreplace.sourceforge.net/